# A lemma on $\ell^p$ spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces, limsup-and-liminf

Can someone tell me how to prove these 2 results (especially 2, as I currently dont need 1)
[image]

The idea given just below the statement isn't making much sense to me. How can we take limit outside the limsup, as has been mentioned in the hint?